# how to combine a value with each of the element of another array in a JSON using jq?

Tags: json, jq

The JSON like this:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "names": [
      "apple",
      "google"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "names": [
      "iphone",
      "ipad",
      "macbook"
    ]
  }
]
```

expected output in tsv

```
1 apple
1 google
2 iphone
2 ipad
2 macbook
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **`map`**

along with *raw-output* option such as

```
jq -r 'map( "\(.id) " + .names[] )[]'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/FgL46-ja0R4)</kbd>

or formatting as ***tsv*** :

```
jq -r 'map( "\(.id) " + .names[] ) | @tsv'
```

which outputs the result on a single line

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/GQOR-dfw-Bz)</kbd>

or use

```
jq -r 'map( "\(.id)\t" + .names[])[]'
```

in order to get tab-delimited results *between attributes* while returning each combinations on separate lines

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/VrlLfFwMTo0)</kbd>

Comment: I think perhaps the second example (for TSV output) doesn't quite give the desired result (all values on a single line). Maybe this instead: `jq -r '.[]|"\(.id)\t" + .names[]'`

Comment: thank you @qmacro your suggestion is pretty good. My initial intent was only to return each combination tab separated considering **tsv**

Comment: Thank you also - I learned about the effect of `+` with the array iterator (`[]`) - I guess because of the commutative nature of `+` the iteration drives the output.